# Provisioning baremetal is giving 'hostname' must be set error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
hw = {
      'datacenter': {'name': 'che01'},
      'hostname': 'baremetal',
      'domain': 'cds.net',
      'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
      'fixedConfigurationPreset': {'keyName': 'S1270_32GB_1X1TBSATA_NORAID'},
      'networkComponents': [{
          'maxSpeed': 1000
          # 'redundancyEnabledFlag': True,
      }],
      'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'UBUNTU_14_64'
  }
  productOrder = slClient['Hardware'].generateOrderTemplate(hw)

order = slClient['Hardware'].createObject(productOrder)
```

Running above code, which is giving this error:

> SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError:
>   SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_MissingCreationProperty): The
>   property 'hostname' must be set to create an instance of
>   'SoftLayer_Hardware'  I hostname is specified, still it is giving
>   hostname property is not set.

Can you please let me know where I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that once you call the [generateOrderTemplate](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/generateOrderTemplate) method, it creates an order container which work for the [verifyOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder) or [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) methods.

So you do not have to use the [createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/createObject) method, instead use the [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method

e.g.

```
import SoftLayer

slClient = SoftLayer.Client()

hw = { 'datacenter':
            {'name': 'che01'},
        'hostname': 'baremetal',
        'domain': 'cds.net',
        'hourlyBillingFlag': True,
        'fixedConfigurationPreset':
            {'keyName': 'S1270_32GB_1X1TBSATA_NORAID'},
        'networkComponents':
            [{ 'maxSpeed': 1000  #'redundancyEnabledFlag': True
            , }],
        'operatingSystemReferenceCode': 'UBUNTU_14_64' }
productOrder = slClient['Hardware'].generateOrderTemplate(hw)

order = slClient['Product_Order'].placeOrder(productOrder)
```